# A problem with new \listing environment

Tags: listings, environments

I'm creating a new environment to include a python code in my latex file.
It works but the code is longer than one page and doesn't continue in the next page, it is cutted and interrupted at the and of the page. And also it's cutted on the right.
How can i fix that?

My environment:

```
\lstnewenvironment{codice_testo}[1][]
{\lstset{basicstyle=\small\ttfamily, columns=fullflexible,
keywordstyle=\color{red}\bfseries, commentstyle=\color{blue},
language=Python, basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny,
stepnumber=1, numbersep=5pt, frame=shadowbox, float=*, #1}}{}
```

Comment: I guess that `float=*` causes the problem. A floating object cannot be larger than one page. However, I have never tried to typeset a listing that is larger than one page.

Comment: As for the truncation on the right side, give the options `breaklines=true` and, at your choice, also `breakautoindent=true` a try.

Comment: I remove `float=*` and now the code goes to the next page, thanks @Matthias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the option `float=*` because a floating object cannot be larger than one page.

Add the option `breaklines=true` to avoid truncation at the right side. The additional option `breakautoindent` is `true` by default which is a good choice. The amount of indentation can be controlled by `breakindent=<dimension>` and defaults to 20 pt. (See manual for version 1.6, page 35.)